# How to teach python what characters are in the image

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I don't know if I'm going the right way when creating a model and it takes a while to create a model with over 16,000 models, so I'd like to know if I'm doing everything right or if there is a bug in my code. This not convert image to text correct.

At the moment I have over 16,000 62x172 photos, each with seven characters. The title of the photos matches what's in the photo, for example:

**2W4Jtsx**

[image]

**4ogface:**

[image]

**qYGo71d:**

[image]

And now, when I do the entire process of creating the model and saving it, when I want to check a picture that existed in the folder from which the model was created, the program can easily read the image, that is:
If in the folder from which the model was created there was an image containing: 2W4Jtsx, there is no problem for the program's response to be good:

[image]

Predicted Captcha (Should be: 2W4Jtsx) -> Decode image: 2W4Jtsx - so it's okay.

The problem appears when captcha never occurred exactly the same as I check, i.e. for example:

In model we have:
**qYGo71d**

[image]

I have similar captcha: qYGo7**sx** not qYGo7**1d**

[image]

**Predicted Captcha (Should be: qYGo7sx) -> Decode image: qYGo71d - BAD!.**

As you can see above, these are two very similar captcha, but it shows the result that is in the model and not the one that should be (sx and the end, not 1d)

When I add an image that was never identical when creating the model, the program shows the decoded image, but not a single sign is inconsistent with reality, even though separate characters must have repeated earlier when creating the model (I understand that one or two characters would not match, but seven ... :( ?)

[image]

**Predicted Captcha (Should be: Hy7S44o) -> Decode image: wgrpgnk - BAD!.**

I think I'm doing something wrong ... will someone help?

```
#importing libraries
import numpy as np 
import os
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
import cv2
import string
```

```
n=len(os.listdir("/home/admin/images/sevencharimages"))
imgshape=(62,172,1) #Image size: 62px - height, 172px - width
character= string.ascii_letters + "0123456789" # all exist chars: (abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789)
nchar = len(character) #total number of char possible for predict result (7,32)
print(n)
print(nchar)
```

Output:

> 16364
> 62

PreProcess for 7 char in each image:

```
#preprocesss image
def preprocess():
  X = np.zeros((n,62,172,1)) #16364*62*172 array with all entries 0
  y = np.zeros((7,n,nchar)) #7*16364*62(7 letters in captcha) with all entries 0

  for i, pic in enumerate(os.listdir("/home/admin/images/sevencharimages")):
    img = cv2.imread(os.path.join("/home/admin/images/sevencharimages", pic), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) #Read image in grayscale format
    pic_target = pic[:-4]#this drops the .png extension from file name and contains only the captcha for training
    
    if len(pic_target) < 8: #captcha is not more than 7 chars
      img = img / 255.0 #scales the image between 0 and 1
      img = np.reshape(img, (62,172, 1)) #reshapes image to width 172px , height 62px
      target=np.zeros((7,nchar)) #creates an array of size 7*62 with all entries 0

      for j, k in enumerate(pic_target):
         index = character.find(k) #index stores the position of letter k of captcha in the character string
         target[j, index] = 1

      X[i] = img #stores all the images
      y[:,i] = target #stores all the info about the letters in captcha of all images

  return X,y
```

Create model def:

```
#create model
def createmodel():
    img = layers.Input(shape=imgshape) # Get image as an input
    conv1 = layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')(img)
    mp1 = layers.MaxPooling2D(padding='same')(conv1) 
    conv2 = layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')(mp1)
    mp2 = layers.MaxPooling2D(padding='same')(conv2)  
    conv3 = layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')(mp2)
    bn = layers.BatchNormalization()(conv3) 
    mp3 = layers.MaxPooling2D(padding='same')(bn)
    
    flat = layers.Flatten()(mp3) #convert the layer into 1-D

    outs = []
    for _ in range(7): #for 7 chars of captcha
        dens1 = layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(flat)
        drop = layers.Dropout(0.5)(dens1)
        res = layers.Dense(nchar, activation='sigmoid')(drop)

        outs.append(res)
    
    # Compile model and return it
    model = Model(img, outs) #create model
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',metrics=["accuracy"])
    return model
```

Predict def:

```
def predict(filepath):
    img = cv2.imread(filepath, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    if img is not None: #image foud at file path
        img = img / 255.0 #Scale image
    else:
        print("Not detected");

    res = np.array(model.predict(img[np.newaxis, :, :, np.newaxis])) #np.newaxis=1  
    result = np.reshape(res, (7, 62)) #reshape the array
    k_ind = []
    probs = []
    for i in result:
        k_ind.append(np.argmax(i)) #adds the index of the char found in captcha

    capt = '' #string to store predicted captcha
    for k in k_ind:
        capt += character[k] #finds the char corresponding to the index
    return capt
```

Create model and train for 7 chars on image:

```
#Create model
model=createmodel();
model.summary();
X,y=preprocess()
X_train, y_train = X[:16364], y[:, :16364]
X_test, y_test = X[16364:], y[:, 16364:]
hist = model.fit(X_train, [y_train[0], y_train[1], y_train[2], y_train[3], y_train[4], y_train[5], y_train[6]], batch_size=32, epochs=60, validation_split=0.2)
model.save("mymodel.h5")
```

Comment: You’re trying to do something that’s deliberately designed to be as difficult as reasonably possible, so of course it’s not going to work very well.

Comment: there is already a trained model for this type of captcha. maybe you can use that

Comment: @LeopardShark This is for my use, not to bypass any captcha online... i want only understand how it working. With only digts on white background i no have problem, but here this is not working....

Comment: @EvilReboot What exactly are you talking about? Where can I go find? Because I've been working on it for two days and trying to compile it :D

Comment: @Karmay checkout this `https://www.phpcaptcha.org/try-securimage/` , from my perspective your images are similar like this. checkout and confirm whether they resemble the same or not.